# How to print vuetify Data table with pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Laravel with Vuetify 2. I want to print all the data in table without pagination.
here what I got.
[image]

```
v-dialog   v-model="salesDialog">
        <v-card id="print">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-data-table
                    :headers="salesListItemHeaders"
                    :items="salesItemData"
                    :search="search" hide-default-footer
                    :disable-pagination="true"
                >
                </v-data-table>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>

    </v-dialog>
```

My Styles

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
        font-size: 20px !important;
    }

    #print, #print * {
        visibility: visible;
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    #title {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #print {
        padding: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

I'm using viewing printable items in v-dialog

Comment: Is there a chance you are already paginating the data in laravel somehow?

Comment: no sir.  I get all the items in the view but when it's come to printing shows fewer items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two props required to achieve this,

```
disable-pagination
hide-default-footer
```

which are used to remove the pagination from vuetify table,

so the final code would be something like this

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
      disable-pagination
      hide-default-footer

></v-data-table>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. but I get the first page only.

Comment: I think it should show all the items, how many total items do you have?

Comment: it depends. let's say I have 50 items but in print, I get like 20 items. I showing printable items in a dialog. I updated the question.

Comment: can you post an updated screenshot as well? now this may be the dialog height issue.

Comment: actually error was in style positioning. if I set element position to fixed pages won't show

Comment: Ok so removing that position property fixed your issue @kas